# Is there a way to detect currently installed IE version and decide if it is up to date?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control, browser-detection

I am trying to detect which version of IE an end-user has installed on their computer (My App uses WebBrowser control).

I need to know which version they are using which may not be as simple as

```
WebBrowser.Version
```

it seems that although that gives the version it does not tell us if the browser is actually using that version or a compatible version.

Also, With the WebBrowser.Version in hand, how would I go about deciding if this is the latest version of IE?

Any ideas, pointers - if not - tell a joke or something!

Cheers

Comment: Latest as in latest for this OS or latest as in latest version released?

Comment: The latest version of IE available for that OS

Answer (score 1):

Does people still use the Webbrowser control when things like Gecko and Webkit exists?

Anyways you can use the windows registry.
[image]

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer").GetValue("Version")
```

Comment: The company wants WebBrowser - what more can I say. But this does not tell me if it is the latest version installed.